# Geometries of Statistical Areas (Statistický obvod) in Czech Republic

Tags: geospatial, census, population

I’m looking for up-to-date census data about total population, age groups, buildings, … for Czech Republic at the highest possible spatial resolution. And I want to visualize them on a map. The smallest units on which data are published seem to be Statistical Areas (Statistický obvod).

[Výsledky sčítání 2021 - otevřená data](https://www.czso.cz/csu/czso/vysledky-scitani-2021-otevrena-data) has the Census 2021 open data in CSV format. The files in the last section contain basic population data on statistical areas as far as I can tell.

The files contain an area ID in the column `uzemi_kod`, but no geometries.

https://geodata.statistika.cz/geonetwork/srv/cze/catalog.search#/metadata/czso-id-metadata-inspire-su-20110326 lists geographical areas for download and this file contains the Statistický obvod: https://geoportal.gov.cz/atom/CSU/SU/SUV_STAT_OBVOD_4258.gml. But they are from 2011.

The 2021 CSV file and the 2011 GML file can be mostly matched by ID. But there are some “holes” where data cannot be joined. I guess some of the statistical areas were redefined between 2011 and 2021 and their IDs changed.

The statistical areas are continuously maintained in the [Registr sčítacích obvodů a budov (RSO)](https://apl.czso.cz/irso4/). On their website you can download the database in DBF format, but it doesn’t contain geometries.

So, I’m looking for the missing piece which are the geometries that match the 2021 census area IDs. Any format would work – Shapefile, GeoJSON, GML, WFS, …. Any pointers would be appreciated.